# Twilio in Node-Red - getting below error

Tags: twilio, node-red

below is the complete command prompt error

```
29 Mar 22:16:20 - [info] Windows_NT 10.0.14393 x64 LE
29 Mar 22:16:21 - [info] Loading palette nodes
29 Mar 22:16:22 - [info] Dashboard version 2.3.5 started at /ui
29 Mar 22:16:22 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
29 Mar 22:16:22 - [warn] [rpi-gpio] Info : Ignoring Raspberry Pi specific node
29 Mar 22:16:22 - [warn] [tail] Not currently supported on Windows.
29 Mar 22:16:22 - [warn] [tcp] Error: tcp in already registered
29 Mar 22:16:22 - [warn] [udp] Error: udp out already registered
29 Mar 22:16:22 - [warn] [twilio] Error: twilio-api already registered
29 Mar 22:16:22 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
29 Mar 22:16:22 - [info] Settings file  : \Users\Charles\.node-red\settings.js
29 Mar 22:16:22 - [info] User directory : \Users\Charles\.node-red
29 Mar 22:16:22 - [info] Flows file     : \Users\Charles\.node-red\flows_LAPTOP-9T4HPKBK.json
29 Mar 22:16:22 - [info] Creating new flow file
29 Mar 22:16:22 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
29 Mar 22:16:22 - [info] Starting flows
29 Mar 22:16:22 - [info] Started flows
express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead .node-red\node_modules\node-red-bluemix-nodes\twilio\56-    twilio-cf.js:64:13
29 Mar 22:27:56 - [info] Stopping flows
29 Mar 22:27:56 - [info] Stopped flows
29 Mar 22:27:56 - [info] Waiting for missing types to be registered:
29 Mar 22:27:56 - [info]  - twilio-api
29 Mar 22:27:56 - [info]  - twilio out
29 Mar 22:28:45 - [info] Stopping flows
29 Mar 22:28:45 - [info] Stopped flows
29 Mar 22:28:45 - [info] Waiting for missing types to be registered:
29 Mar 22:28:45 - [info]  - twilio-api
29 Mar 22:28:45 - [info]  - twilio out
```

I am just using **inject** and **twilio** to send an SMS from my allotted phone number to my registered phone number in `Node-Red`

[image]

Comment: The error says you don't have the twillio nodes installed. You need to provide a lot more information about what you did to get here

Comment: added additional details - thx for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have multiple copies of the Twillio, TCP & UDP nodes installed.

I would guess you have installed the Twillio node both locally and globally. You need to remove one of them.

How you've ended up with 2 copies of the TCP and UDP nodes is stranger as these are core nodes